# Swift 4 Change Physics Gravity

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift4

since swift 4 the old gravity code doesn't work anymore...

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,0)
```

That´s not working ↑
can you give me the new code?
Thanks!

Comment: "does not work" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: _since swift 4_ Really? Your code does not compile with Xcode 8.3.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGVectorMake` has been deprecated. Use the following syntax to initialise a CGVector:

`self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)`

Or, since you want a vector with both components 0:

`self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector.zero`